# Node - selecting values from nested JSON

Tags: json, node.js

Hi I'm working on node js and I wanted to get some values.

So I tried using `data.list['dt']`, but was unsuccessful.

Actually I want to show: **`dt, day, humidity, description`** .

Please help me to show this. Thanks in advance!

```
"list": [
{
  "dt": 1487242800,
  "temp": {
    "day": 286.67,
    "min": 272.78,
    "max": 286.67,
    "night": 273.34,
    "eve": 277.05,
    "morn": 281.56
  },
  "pressure": 972.73,
  "humidity": 75,
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "sky is clear",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "speed": 1.81,
  "deg": 248,
  "clouds": 0
}
]
```

Comment: list is an array so you need to use it like data.list[0]['dt']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value for key List in your data json is an array so first you need to access element in list by index and then keys dt, day, humidity, description etc. like follows:

```
data.list[0]['dt']
```

Answer (score 1):

To show dt, day, humidity, and description values.

Like @hurricane said:

```
data.list[0]['dt'];
data.list[0]['temp']['day'];
data.list[0]['humidity'];
data.list[0]['weather']['description'];
```